# How to refer to java-library in gradle file?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have in an Android Studio lib modules build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
}
```

and in a `module.gradle` file follwoing:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    (android.hasProperty('applicationVariants') ? android.'applicationVariants' : android.'libraryVariants')
            .all { variant ->
               //..
            }
}
```

As I understood, the `android` variable refers to the mentioned `com.android.library`. I have another lib with

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
}
```

and **not** `id("com.android.library")` in its build.gradle. How can I refer (same as `android`) to this `java-library` plugin in mentioned `module.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the plugin by its id:

```kotlin
project.afterEvaluate {
   plugins.withId("java-library") {
      println("Found it!")
   }
}
```